# Why ValueError: Need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python

I know others have asked about this error, but I'm not sure why I keep getting this error for this code.
I'm writing a code to open and read a textfile, then replace each letter in it with a new letter. The letters and their replacements are specified in my dictionary "replacements."

This is my code right now:

```
def decode(text):
    replacements={'a':'L','b':'A','c':'O','d':'Z','e':'M','f':'V','g':'R','h':'B','i':'U','j':'S','k':'Q','l':'K','m':'Y','n':'J','o':'W','p':'H','q':'E','r':'X','s':'T','t':'P','u':'F','v':'I','w':'G','x':'C','y':'D','z':'N'}
    infile=open(text).read()
    outfile=open("output.txt",'w')
    for letter in infile:
        for old,new in replacements:
            newtext=infile.replace(old,new)
            outfile.write(newtext)
    infile.close()
```

When I run the code, the error message comes up for the line "for old,new in replacements" and tells me it needs more than 1 value to unpack. I'm very new to programming .. can someone please explain why I'm getting this error?

Comment: What is `replacements` in your real code? It looks like a half dictionary / half set. Could you edit the question so it's exactly as in your code?

Comment: sorry i was trying to save time and not type it all out. i changed it

Answer (score 5):

```
 for old,new in replacements:
```

Will iter the keys in a dict.

```
 for old,new in replacements.iteritems():
```

Will iterate the key and value in the dict

Comment: @Patrick no, that shouldn't make a difference. The new error lies somewhere else.

Comment: @user3074142 I guess the new error is that you assume `infile` is the `file` object but you have already made it into `str` by `.read()`.

Comment: @user3074142 Strange enough! What is the error you have for the moment? The modified code work well on my machine.

Comment: Maybe the OP is using python3 and thus he should use `items()` instead of `iteritems()`. However without the **full** traceback of the error this is just a guess. By the way: `items()` would also work in python2 and hence is a more general solution, although in python2 it is less efficient. Since the question doesn't specify a version I'd use the most general solution and mention `iteritems()` as a more efficient solution for python2.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jakob's answer solved the problem but I would like to rearrange the code a little bit.

```
def decode(text):
    replacements={'a':'L','b':'A','c':'O','d':'Z','e':'M','f':'V','g':'R','h':'B','i':'U','j':'S','k':'Q','l':'K','m':'Y','n':'J','o':'W','p':'H','q':'E','r':'X','s':'T','t':'P','u':'F','v':'I','w':'G','x':'C','y':'D','z':'N'}
    with open(text, 'r') as infile:
        instr = infile.read()
        for old,new in replacements.iteritems():
            instr = instr.replace(old, new)    
        with open("output.txt", 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(instr)
```

1. Doing replacement doesn't require looping through all the letters. It will find convert all matches.
2. It is easier to use `with open`, since it will take care of `close` automatically.

Hope these suggestions help you learn Python.